# QByteArray indexOf deprecated?

Tags: c++, qt, qbytearray

I'm using Qt 5.15.2, I have the following code:

```
    QByteArray arybytData = mpsckIncoming->readAll();
    bool blnHTTP = false;
    
    if ( arybytData.startsWith("GET / HTTP/") == true ) {
    //HTTP Request, probably from browser, jump to end of header
        const QString cstrHeaderTerminator("\r\n\r\n");
        int intHdrEnd;
        
        if ( (intHdrEnd = arybytData.indexOf(cstrHeaderTerminator)) == -1 ) {
```

The line using `QByteArray::indexOf()` has the text:

```
'indexOf' is deprecated: Use QString's toUtf8(), toLatin1() or toLocal8Bit()
```

I don't understand this since none of the suggested functions are anything like the function of `QByteArrray::indexOf()`.

Should I just ignore it?

I'm using:

```
Qt Creator 4.14.0
Based on Qt 5.15.2 (Clang 11.0 (Apple), 64 bit)
Built on Dec 17 2020 07:57:30
From revision 909f74dc56
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only `QByteArray::indexOf(const QString& str, int from)` is deprecated. The other overloads are still available.

What you're meant to do is to use `QString::toUtf8()`, `QString::toLatin1()` or `QString::toLocal8Bit()` to retrieve a `QByteArray` representing the `QString` which can then be passed to the non-deprecated overloads of `QByteArray::indexOf()`.

The reason for this is most likely that the `QByteArray::indexOf()` overload that accepts the `QString` does not know how to interpret the string from an encoding point of view. Therefore, you have to do the "conversion" explicitly. I didn't look into this so maybe there are other reasons for the deprecation of that function.

Looking at the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray-obsolete.html#indexOf-3) of the deprecated function in question we learn that this used `QString::toUtf8()` internally, therefore you can adapt your code like this to get the same behavior:

```cpp
if ( (intHdrEnd = arybytData.indexOf(cstrHeaderTerminator.toUtf8())) == -1 ) {
```